# SharedPreferences gives null pointer in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, sharedpreferences

This is my class:

```
public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
{
    Context c;
    MainActivity main;
    String profileid;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() { 

}  


@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) { 

    try {


        String semail = MainActivity.email.getText().toString();
        String spassword = MainActivity.password.getText().toString();

        String savedresponse;

        String postURL = "http://(My URL)";

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL); 

        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

        int timeoutConnection = 5000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);

        int timeoutSocket = 5000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

        post.setHeader("Content-type","application/json");


        JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();
        jsonobj.put("username", semail);
        jsonobj.put("password", spassword);

        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonobj.toString());

        post.setEntity(se);
        HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);

        HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();  

        savedresponse = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

        if (resEntity != null)
        {    
            Log.i("RESPONSE",savedresponse);

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(savedresponse);

            int responseCode;

            responseCode = json.getInt("ResponseCode");



            profileid = json.getString("ProfileID");

            SharedPreferences prefs = main.getSharedPreferences("ProfileName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.putString("ProfileCookie", profileid);
            editor.commit();


                if(responseCode == 100) {

                    MainActivity.email.setText("");
                    MainActivity.password.setText("");

                    main.Login();

            }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(c, "Username or Password wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }



        } 
        if (resEntity == null)
        {
            Log.i("NO RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
            Toast.makeText(c, "NO RESPONSE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 


    return null; 
} 


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result)  
{ 

 }
```

}

This is what i got in error log:

```
10-04 02:30:07.283: W/System.err(1015): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-04 02:30:07.283: W/System.err(1015): at      com.example.testproject.LoginTask.doInBackground(LoginTask.java:88)
10-04 02:30:07.283: W/System.err(1015): at com.example.testproject.LoginTask.doInBackground(LoginTask.java:1)
10-04 02:30:07.283: W/System.err(1015): at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-04 02:30:07.283: W/System.err(1015): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
10-04 02:30:07.283: W/System.err(1015): at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-04 02:30:07.283: W/System.err(1015): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
10-04 02:30:07.294: W/System.err(1015): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
10-04 02:30:07.294: W/System.err(1015): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

When i debug i found that app crashes when comes to shared preferences line, i am stuck here from last two days and not able to find any solution

Please help me to correct my code.
Please post corrected code if possible.

Comment: Its giving error because you have not initialize your `MainActivity` in your code and you are directly referring it. You should use the context of your current activity i.e. `SharedPreferences prefs = c.getSharedPreferences("ProfileName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

instead Of `SharedPreferences prefs = main.getSharedPreferences("ProfileName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing UI operation in doInBackground method, Remember doInBackground Method is for background operations only. If you want to interact with UI , onPostExecute method is to be used

Remove

```
                MainActivity.email.setText("");
                MainActivity.password.setText(""); 
             & Toast Messages
```

from doinBackground and add in `onPostExecute` method

your

```
  onPostExecute(){

    if(responseCode == 100) {

                MainActivity.email.setText("");
                MainActivity.password.setText("");

                main.Login();

        }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(c, "Username or Password wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }



    } 
    if (resEntity == null)
    {
        Log.i("NO RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
        Toast.makeText(c, "NO RESPONSE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: but why app stops on sharedprefernces

Comment: @user2841993 check out my answer i have defined why it stops on sharepreference.

Comment: I guess you have not instantiated new object of 'main' in your line                                                              SharedPreferences prefs = main.getSharedPreferences("ProfileName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);                                                             do like this                                                                          main=new Main(); (Object of Main class)

Answer (score 0):

You have this

```
 MainActivity main;
```

But where have you initialzied `main`?. Even if you initialize its wrong assuming its a activity class.

You can get the value from sharepreferences in your activity class and pass param to asynctask `doInbackground`. Also you can get the editext values in your activity class and pass the same to asynctask `doInbackground`

You cannot update ui from `doInbackground`

```
MainActivity.email.setText("");
MainActivity.password.setText("");
Toast.makeText(c, "NO RESPONSE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do the UI related work in your `doInBackground` method. Move the below line in your `onCreate()` method

> ```
>      String semail = MainActivity.email.getText().toString();
>     String spassword = MainActivity.password.getText().toString();
> ```

In your `doInBackground` return your requestcode and write the below code in your `onPostExecute()` method.

> ```
>     @Override
>     protected void onPostExecute(Void result)  
>      { 
>          f(result== 100) {
>                 MainActivity.email.setText("");
>                 MainActivity.password.setText("");
>                 main.Login();
>            }
>             else
>             {
>                 Toast.makeText(c, "Username or Password wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>             }
>       }
> ```

Also you have not initialize your `MainActivity` in your code and you are directly referring it. You should use the context of your current activity i.e. `SharedPreferences prefs = c.getSharedPreferences("ProfileName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Define your context as `Context c="youractivityname.this";`

Answer (score 0):

You are able to get SharedPreference instance in background. The problem is that your "main" instance has not been initialized.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("ProfileName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Only background process should be processed in doInBackground() method. You should place later-on code in your onPostExecute() method.